# How can i use CQL Filter [attr IN List ]?

Tags: cql, geotools

I am trying to use the In filter of CQL on my query as cited on the documentation but it is not working and the parsing error I'm getting says there is no IN filter in CQL :

```
org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLException: Encountered "IS IN" at line 1, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
    "(" ...
    ":" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "." ...
    <NOT> ...
    "like" ...
    "is" "null" ...
    "is" <NOT> ...
    "exists" ...
    "does-not-exist" ...
    "tequals" ...
    "before" ...
    "after" ...
    "during" ...
    "between" ...
    <EQ> ...
    <GT> ...
    <LT> ...
    <GTE> ...
    <LTE> ...
    <NEQ> ...
     Parsing : point_type_id IS IN ('1','2','3').
```

is there any fix to this error or i will use multiple filter and combine them with OR ??

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to parse `IS IN` which is [invalid](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#predicate) - try just `point_type_id IN ('1','2','3')`.

Comment: I tried that but it s not working either , if you noticed the grammar of CQL doesnt have IN at all as viewed in the error stack

Comment: You should use ECQL